# how to avoid result set closed error while doing order by

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

This is the piece of code that i try to run via jdbc and sqlite

```
Statement s = conPlayer.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM Stats "+ "WHERE pos = " + "'%" + pos + "%'" + " ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 54");


System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));
```

Comment: should that be `pos like `

Comment: Don't forget to use `while(rs.next()) {...}` to check for more data and advance to the first row of the `ResultSet`.

Comment: Please learn how to use prepared statements, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I will pass pos= "1=1 --" ;)